# Changing the order of integration of these two double integrals.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> $\int^2_1dx\int^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}_{2-x}f(x,y)dy$
> $\int^e_1dx\int^{ln(x)}_{0}f(x,y)dy$

My attempts: 
**For the first Integral:** 
I can see that $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ defines half of a circle with radius $1$. 
And $2-x$ is basically a line, I drew them, and I can see that if I wanted to change the order of integration, $y$ will be between $0$ and $1$, and now my problem is $x$, I need to get what is the upper $x$ from this equation $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2} \Longrightarrow y^2=2x-x^2$, but how do I keep going? I'm not succeeding to get $x$ from that equation. 

**For the second integral**: 
I can see the area between $y=ln(x)$, $x=e$, $x=1$. 
In order to change the order of integration, I must see the borders of $y$, and that's the intersection between $y=ln(x)$ and $x=e$, which is $y=1$. 
So the integral will be: 
$\int^1_0dy\int^{e}_{e^y}f(x,y)dx$ 
Any help and feedback is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct.

For the first one, yes you are right on bound of $y$.

For $x$, it is bound below by line $x+y = 2$ so $x \geq 2 - y$.

For upper bound,

$y=\sqrt{2x-x^2} \implies x^2 - 2x + y^2 = 0$

Rewriting, $(x-1)^2 = 1 - y^2 \implies x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$

Please note that for any given $y \ne \pm1$, there are two values of $x$ on the circle, one to the left of $x = 1$ and one to the right of $x = 1$ as the circle is centered at $(1, 0)$. Here we are interested in,

$x = 1 + \sqrt{1-y^2}$

So bounds are $ 2 - y \leq x \leq 1 + \sqrt{1-y^2}, 0 \leq y \leq 1$